# Function expressions are not supported in decorators

Tags: angular, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Angular app to heroku. However, if I run

```
git push heroku master
```

During compilation I am getting

```
remote:        ERROR in app/component/login/login.component.ts(24,5): Error during template compile of 'LoginComponent'
remote:          Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'listAnimation'
remote:            'listAnimation' references 'ɵ0'
remote:              'ɵ0' contains the error at app/component/login/login.animation.ts(5,15)
remote:                Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

But there is no `ɵ0` referenced in my `LoginComponent`:

**login.animation.ts**

```js
import {
  sequence, trigger, stagger, animate, style, group, query as q, transition, keyframes, animateChild,
  state
} from '@angular/animations';
const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);

export const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation', [

  transition(':enter', [
    query('.container', style({opacity: 0}), {optional: true}),
    query('.container', stagger('150ms', [
      animate('150ms ease-in', keyframes([
        style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(100%)', offset: 0}),
        style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 1.0})
      ]))]), {optional: true})
  ]),

  transition('* => loggedIn', [
    query('.container', style({opacity: 1}), {optional: true}),
      query('.container', stagger('-150ms', [
        animate('150ms ease-in', keyframes([
          style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)', offset: 0}),
          style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(100%)', offset: 1.0})
        ]))]), {optional: true})
    ])

]);
```

**login.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../service/authentication.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {NGXLogger} from 'ngx-logger';
import {listAnimation} from './login.animation';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  styles: [`
      .mat-card {
        margin: 5%;
        max-width: 300px;
      }
      .mat-form-field {
        width: 100%;
      }`],
  animations: [
    listAnimation
  ],
  host: {
    '[@listAnimation]': 'true'
  }
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  viewState: string = 'init';    

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private router: Router, private logger: NGXLogger) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.logger.debug('Already logged in. Goto /home.');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {

    this.viewState = 'loggedIn';
  }

  animationDone() {
    this.logger.info('animationDone');
    if (this.viewState == 'loggedIn') {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  }

}
```

So what exactly is the problem here?

---

I tried replacing

```js
const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);
```

with

```js
export function query(s, a, o={optional:true}) {
  return q(s,a,o);
}
```

but that didn't help either ..

Comment: `const query = (s,a,o={optional:true})=>q(s,a,o);` is your issue. As the build error suggests, consider changing it to an exported function. Could you also please post the code of the module(s) that use those animations ?

Comment: @trichetriche Hm, I tried that - but it didn't change the error. I've added the component's code.

Comment: The issue is related to a lot of things, it also happens when you try to create functions for routing. If what they suggested didn't work, consider moving this function no another file and export it, and if it still doesn't work, then go back to the good old hard coding of `{ optional: true }` directly in your queries !

Comment: @trichetriche Okay, I kind of made it work. You were right. Translating it to an exported function did the trick. But how weird is that - why would that not work for production ..

Comment: I just have found the topic that helped me understand why it failed. I give it to you even though you resolved your issue, it still could help you understand at least ! https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15587

Comment: @trichetriche I'd be glad to accept your answer if you want to provide one :)

Comment: what did you end up doing to get this working?

Comment: @SteveFitzsimons I know my question says I tried it but I think that is misleading. Have you tried transforming your `const whatever = ..` into `export function whatever() ..`?

Comment: Yea I did but couldn't get it to work correctly. Would be good to have the answer as what actually worked for you rather than a link to a github issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As your error says, you need to export the function. Decorators don't accept function calls into their properties.

You can find more information on this github issue : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15587

Answer (score 23):

In my case error was caused by:

```
export const listAnimation = ()...
```

instead of:

```
export function listAnimation()...
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to refactor code like this:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: loadStuff,
  deps: [InitRolesService],
  multi: true
}
```

and then export function

```
export function loadStuff(service: InitService) {
   return () => service.load().subscribe(data => { ... }));
}
```